# Сетевое хранилище FreeBSD

Tags: nas, freebsd

У кого нибудь есть ман по отказоустойчивым хранилищам на FreeBSD?
Уточняю количество машин не имеет значения.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Мана как такового нет.
Могу направить в сторону проекта [FreeNAS](http://freenas.org/FreeNAS).
И упомянуть, что в зависимости от требований может понадобиться:

1. Объединение дисков в массивы для обеспечения отказоустойчивости и скорости работы
2. Агрегирование сетевых линков, QoS.
3. Специальное железо, которое будет уметь п.1 или п.2. Необходимость в софте обычно ограничивается драйверами этих специальных аппаратных средств.

Comment: Про рейды я давно знаю, транкинг тоже знакомая тема, интересует что можно сделать кроме этого.

Comment: Купить кластер с технологией ChipKill или аналогами (отключение из адресного пространства модулей памяти с битыми ячейками на горячую) :-) Все зависит от уровня задач: потребностей и доступных ресурсов, в первую очередь, финансовых.

Comment: Повторяю мне нужно решение на FreeBSD